# Upgrade JS only react-native library to RN 0.60

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I have a react-native component library, which only contains javascript code. I don't have ios/android directory (in library). I want to make it compatible with react-native 0.60. My library has some dependencies which which needs linking. Until this point I was just asking consumers to link these dependencies manually.

Now for autolinking (in RN 0.60) to work, I will need to a podspec for my project. But I don't really have any ios code (or directory) in my library. So I can't create podspec. So in this case, only way I can see is to ask consumers of my library to manually install all the NPM dependencies of my libraries and then `pod install`. Is there some other way that I can configure it in my library, that will let cocoapods know to install the dependencies of my library as well?

P.S. I am not really much familiar with ios or cocoapods. So if this question sounds a bit silly, please pardon me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run following command to generate ios/android directories:

```
react-native upgrade --legacy true
```

Then you can run following command to install iOS dependencies when the directories generated:

```
cd ios
pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible at least with version **0.60**, Because of breaking changes in this version, If you are on the version before **0.60** and wanted to upgrade on **0.60** you have to face native issues and breaking changes in the native libraries as well because for now most of the libraries have two different versions one for above **0.60** and other for below **0.60**.
When you will try to upgrade on **0.60** this version also have native changes and also auto linking is been introduced so some native libraries can also cause problem due to this.
My Recommendation is to use Upgrade helper tool and get an idea about the changes that you need on every version.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading